# OpenCV with NodeJS binding Installtion

Tags: node.js, opencv, heroku, contour

I want to make a live stream face detection project OpenCV & NodeJS binding. My goal is eventually to deploy this on Heroku with NodeJS backend and HTML frontend. I am following

```
npm install opencv
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/opencv

I am following the installation procedure for Windows. Now, I want to test if all my installations are complete and it says on the website above to

```
Examples
Run the examples from the parent directory.
```

However, I don't know what command to use. I have cloned the git repo and it looks very confusing to me as to which file to run with what command. For example, could it be

```
node server.js
```

Also, on that website it says the build is failing with only 45% coverage. Does it mean it is not working?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do this part Download peterbraden/node-opencv fork git clone https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv

Then in the parent dir of that cloned repo on your system, you have to test the code they give.  They examples are images.

```
cv.readImage("./examples/files/mona.png", function(err, im){
  im.detectObject(cv.FACE_CASCADE, {}, function(err, faces){
    for (var i=0;i<faces.length; i++){
      var x = faces[i]
      im.ellipse(x.x + x.width/2, x.y + x.height/2, x.width/2, x.height/2);
    }
    im.save('./out.jpg');
  });
})
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! I have the repo by peterbraden already. I don't know how to run this example. I see a lot of face detection javascript file in the example directory. How would I be able to run it on the browser?

Comment: I am guessing that I need to run node on my local? Or just open it with browser directly?

Answer (score -2):

I think that you need some basic things. like.. 
$> brew install opencv